# Unable to reach server by SSH

Tags: ssh, vps

In a state of *"only 10 more minutes left until the weekend"* I did an `apt-get upgrade` last Friday to ignorantly fix the reported shellshock error. The upgrade seemingly went fine and I logged of the server thinking everything was dandy. Now however I am unable to log into the server; the connection get's established but then simply hangs.

Worth noticing is that my first connection attempt was successful. I.e I got the password prompt and logged in, but was meet with an incredibly "sluggish" terminal. Thinking a reboot would help, I did just that. Afterwards it froze completely.

As this is an VPS I am unable to reach it any other way. Is there anything I can attempt other then ask my hosting provider to wipe the VPS? I have backups, so other then a whole lot of work it's not the end of the world.

The VPS is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here is the connection log with tripled verbosity.

```
kgv@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ssh user@my-domain.com -vvv
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my-domain.com [77.235.62.109] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kgv/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
```

... From there it stops. No timeout, no errors.

Comment: The VPS I know do have a management interface of sorts, that provide console access. Are you sure you don't have something similar?